# Design Service Manager Class which uses external services using GUICE

Tags: java, design-patterns, guice

In my application I have a Service Manager that handles all my requests. Now this Service Manager uses external services in order to fulfill some particular kind of requests.

For example,consider below sample code:

```
 Class ServiceManager{

    private final A a;
    private final B b;

    private ExternalService externalService; 


      @Inject
      public ServiceManager(A a, B b)
      {
                this.a =a;
                this.b =b;
      }

      public void processIncomingRequestUsingExternalService(){...}


      }
```

Now in order initialize ExternalService which approach is better using GUICE

- Use setter injection, as in future there might be 'n' number of different type of external service come into picture which this Service Manager might want to use.
- Or use constructor injection, as I have used for class A and B objects which are internal class of my application.

Note:- Here ExternalService is a Helper for External Service.

Comment: Constructor injection > all (e.g. http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/). Also almighty manger classes are bad. Single Responsibilty Principle still applies so large n = usually bad design.

Comment: @zapl My point with large n was say 2 - 3 external services which my manager might have to use. Will it be good to add all those external service helpers in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor injection has following advantages over setter injection:

- Explicitly declare dependencies to whoever is reading the code.
- Unit testing becomes cleaner.
- Dependencies can be marked ‘final’, thereby increasing immutability.

A good documentation that discusses the differences in more detail: https://www.petrikainulainen.net/software-development/design/why-i-changed-my-mind-about-field-injection/